# Preventing Ios device from scrolling to top when the upper part of the window is pressed

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile

My problem is that when the user has scrolled down and clicked on the upper level of my fixed navigation bar. Instead of it linking to a new page, it will scroll the window to the top of the page. Is there anyway of preventing this using javascript or meta data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at the scrollsToTop property of the UIScrollView / UITableView which is providing the scrolling